# Proving $\operatorname{Im}(A) = \operatorname{Ker}(A^T)^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

so for any Matrix above $R$ I'd like to prove this equation.
So far I've been able to prove $\operatorname{Im}(A) \subset  Ker(A^T)^\perp$
however I can't figure how I can prove the other way around. 
All help is highly appreciated.

Comment: For $x\in\ker(A^T)$, by definition $A^Tx=0$. Hence, for any $y$, $\langle y,A^Tx\rangle=0$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: no, not entirely

Comment: We have $0=\langle y,A^Tx\rangle=\langle Ay,x\rangle$. As $y$ was arbitrary, $x\in \im(A)^\perp$. Notice that $(\im(A)^\perp)^\perp=\im(A)$.

Answer (score 4):

$\dim\operatorname{Ker}(A^T)^{\perp}=n-\dim\operatorname{Ker}(A^T)=n-\dim\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\dim\operatorname{Im}(A)$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the kernel of $A^T$ is exactly the perpendicular complement of the image, since

$$A^Tx = \begin{bmatrix} v_1^T \\ v_2^T \\ \vdots \\ v_n^T\end{bmatrix}x = \begin{bmatrix} v_1^Tx \\ v_2^Tx \\ \vdots \\ v_n^Tx\end{bmatrix}$$

must be the zero vector if and only if $x$ is orthogonal to the columns of $A$. So, we have

$$\operatorname{im}(A)^{\perp} = \ker(A^T).$$

Since we’re in a finite-dimensional vector space, this implies that

$$\operatorname{im}(A) = (\operatorname{im}(A)^{\perp})^{\perp} = \ker(A^T)^{\perp}.$$